# 特定の箇所WEBスクレイピングができない

Tags: python, python3, web-scraping

PythonでWEBページをスクレイピングしたいです。
[サイト](https://www.centrair.jp/flight/search/?da=A&id=D&fd=20220510)から航空会社(コードシェア)などのフライト情報を取得したいと考えています。

Selenium・BeautifulSoupで以下のコードを試してみたのですが、航空会社(コードシェア)だけが取得できません。

コードのどこがいけないのかスクレイピングに詳しい方教えていただけませんでしょうか。

HTML

```
<div class="flight-codeshare"><ul><li><span class="flight-tail"><img src="/sys-assets/img/flight/airline/ANA-tail.png" alt="" class="fluid-image"></span><span class="flight-code">ANA3166</span></li></ul></div>
```

一部のコード、"ANA3166" を取得したいです。

```
 # 航空会社(コードシェア)
    fa = li.select_one('span.flight-codeshare')
    data['航空会社(コードシェア)'] = fa.text if fa else ''
```

全体コード

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt, date, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

file_time= dt.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")

today= dt.now().strftime("%Y/%m/%d")

#保存ファイル指定
file="test"+file_time+".csv"

#url指定
url = 'https://www.centrair.jp/flight/search/?da=A&id=D&fd=20220510'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
#driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\selenium\chromedriver.exe")

#フライ情報のサイトを開く
driver.get(url)

#5秒待機
time.sleep(5)
#BeautifulSoup指定
html = driver.page_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

tbl = []
for li in soup.select('div.js-flight-search-result ul li'):
    data = {}
    # 定刻[変更]
    ft = li.select_one('span.flight-time-init')
    if ft is None: continue
    data['定刻[変更]'] = ft.text
    ct = li.select_one('span.flight-changetime')
    if ct: data['定刻[変更]'] += f'\n{ct.text}'
    # 出発地[経由]
    st = li.select_one('span.flight-destination')
    data['出発地[経由]'] = st.text if st else ''
    
    #便名
    fn = li.select_one('span.flight-airline')
    data['便名'] = fn.text if fn else ''

    # 航空会社(コードシェア)
    fa = li.select_one('span.flight-codeshare')
    data['航空会社(コードシェア)'] = fa.text if fa else ''

    # ターミナル
    term = li.select_one('span[class*=flight-terminal]')
    data['ターミナル'] = term.text if term else ''

    # 機種
    model = li.select_one('span.flight-status-text02')
    data['機種'] = model.text.split(':')[-1].strip() if model else ''
    # 現在の状況
    status = li.select_one('span.flight-status-icon')
    data['現在の状況'] = status.text if status else ''
    #
    tbl.append(data)

df = pd.DataFrame(tbl)
print(df)

# #Excel形式でハルエネ出力-------------------
# #df.to_excel(file,index=False,encoding='utf-8')
df.to_csv(file,index=False,encoding="utf_8_sig")
```

お手数ですが、よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

該当部分のhtmlがこんな感じなので：

```
<li class="hour10">
  <a href="/flight/detail.html?fno=A-D-20220510-ibx66">
    <div class="flight-time flight-time-change font-roboto">
      <span class="flight-time-init">
        <span>10:10</span>
      </span>
      <span class="flight-changetime">09:59</span>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-main">
      <span class="flight-tail"><img src="/sys-assets/img/flight/airline/IBX-tail.png" alt="" class="fluid-image"></span>
      <span class="flight-destination">大分</span>
      <span class="flight-airline">
        <span class="flight-code">IBX 66</span>
        <span class="flight-airline-name">IBEXエアラインズ</span>
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-codeshare">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="flight-tail"><img src="/sys-assets/img/flight/airline/ANA-tail.png" alt="" class="fluid-image"></span>
          <span class="flight-code">ANA3166</span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="flight-boarding"><span class="flight-terminal font-roboto">T1</span></div>
    <div class="flight-status">
      <span class="flight-status-icon">到着済み</span>
      <div><span class="flight-status-text02">機種 : CRJ7</span></div>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

こんな風にすれば出来るのでは？

```
    # 航空会社(コードシェア)
    fa = li.select_one('div.flight-codeshare')
    fa = fa.select_one('span.flight-code') if fa else ''
    data['航空会社(コードシェア)'] = fa.text if fa else ''
```

---

**コメント対応**

コードシェアが複数ある場合も抽出できるようにするには以下になるでしょう。
複数ある場合の区切り記号を変えたい場合は、`','.join()`の`,`を変えれば良いでしょう。

```
    # 航空会社(コードシェア)
    fa = li.select_one('div.flight-codeshare')
    cdshare = ','.join([s.text for s in fa.find_all(class_='flight-code') if s])
    data['航空会社(コードシェア)'] = cdshare if cdshare else ''
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。取得出来ました。すいません上記の場合1個のコードシェアしか取れないです。複数がある場合はどのように指定すれば良いでしょうか。
もし分かりましたら、教えていただけますか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。上記の方法で出来ました。